# DNS Server 2008 R2 from 2003 - Stand Alone -

Tags: domain-name-system, best-practices

We have just implemented two new windows 2008 r2 stand alone servers running dns and they took the place of our old 2003 stand alone servers. Is there residual clean up that would need to be done on our new servers since the old ones have been decommissioned?

We had all four servers running at the same time and gradually replaced the first 2003 w/ a 2008 master server and then still had a 2003 and a 2008 secondary server in place.

We just recently removed the 2003 secondary server and are noticing odd behaviors with the two 2008 servers. when we run a best practices analysis on our secondary it comes back w/ the following error for all zones including reverse look-up zones:

Title:
DNS: Zone domainname.net transfers from the primary to the secondary DNS server must be successful.

Severity:
Error

Date:
2/7/2013 11:05:56 AM

Category:
Configuration

Issue:
The results of the last zone transfer were 1460 for the zone domainname.net.

Impact:
Contents of the zone domainname.net on this DNS server are out of date.

Resolution:
Verify that zone transfers are allowed to this DNS server.

the best practices on the master server come back clean.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the Microsoft Whitepapers on the procedure?

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd379558(v=ws.10).aspx

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755303.aspx

In general, the guides that Microsoft puts out for their migration procedures are pretty good.  That would be the first place to check if you haven't already.

Comment: I think we did it backwards.  We started with the primary/master DNS server.  According to Microsoft, we should have started with the secondary and then migrate the master.   So any recommendations on how to, i guess, redo this.  Can we promote our secondary to be the master then following microsofts instructions?